# Error while parsing JSON nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

The following data is retrieved from the MongoDB

```
console.log(x)
```

The output

```
{ _id: 54473495721e8a7386959897,
  tag: 'java',
  data: 
   [ 
     { view: '2342343', date: '2001/1/25' }
   ]
}
```

While parsing using JSON.parse

```
var dataJson = JSON.parse(x);
```

it thwors the below error

```
undefined:1
{ _id: 54473495721e8a7386959897,
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
    at Object.parse (native)
```

Comment: Looks `x` is already an Object. Dont need to `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

white space gives error in JSON replace it first

```
x = x.replace(/\s/g, '');
x = JSON.stringify(x);
x = JSON.parse(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already an javascript object so dont need parsing, do you want to convert it as json string?

if yes you can convert to JSON with

```
  JSON.stringify(x);
```